# Can OS X be installed on the ssd part of the fusion drive?

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, mac-mini, fusion-drive

I am looking at purchasing a mac mini and need to decide on a storage option.
I want either an ssd or the fusion drive however I am not sure whether OS X can be installed on the SSD part of the fusion drive which is one of the main reasons that i want an SSD.

Comment: I haven't tried unbonding the core storage, but I'm pretty sure you'd be better off just picking SSD or HDD or fusion and trusting you can't optimize things better than Apple. The current Mac Mini aren't usually IO bound so it's not clear what you're end goal is although I am a bit intrigued.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there's a way to install OS X on the SSD. It's called "install OS X on the Fusion Drive."

The Fusion Drive automatically puts the most frequently-used files on the SSD. When there are vital system files that your hard drive needs to access in its every waking moment, there's really no reason why the Fusion Drive would ever demote it to the HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

Fusion drive has its own algorithm to determine which individual file goes to which drive, based on frequency of access. It doesn't offer any interface to configure the location of files. Moreover, it doesn't even list out which file belongs to which drive. In fact, the only way to know where a file is, is to read the file while the user monitor data flow from both drives.

I don't see why you need to force the entire copy of OSX onto SSD. Frequently used portions of the system, such as start up routine, are most definitely on SSD. There is no reason to have the icons file of some hidden app that an user never use also forced onto SSD.

If you want the entirety of system files on SSD against all, you will need to run the two drives desperately, in the lame way. Then you can put `/Appications` and `/Users` in appropriate drives.

If you want to put certain files always on HDD. you can create a partition on HDD, outside of Fusion Drive. Files on this partition will never end up in SDD. Vice versa does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

I just loaded my OS X onto the SSD part of my Fusion Drive without any problems. During setup it asked me which drive I wanted it installed on and I picked the SSD part.